# strtolower() on an array

Tags: php, arrays, string

Using [strtolower()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) on an array, is there a way to make the output below lower case?

```
<?=$rdata['batch_id']?>
strtolower($rdata['batch_id'])
```

Comment: The question is not clear.

Comment: @zerkms: I think the question is does that code would modify the value of `$rdata['batch_id']` would change and the answer is no

Comment: @RageZ: I thought so too, but it is so obvious that I prefer to think that I just misunderstood his expectations ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: yeah nothing to do with what we thought ...

Comment: also you should use `mb_strtolower($string)` if there is a possibility of have non-english characters in your string: [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5c67223f0a0a17d743d98854a1c43737996333e9)

Comment: Note: Some of the answers were invalidated by revision 2 of the question (not by the OP).

Comment: Is that even valid PHP, with the placement of `<?` and `?>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may mean [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php):

```
<?php echo strtolower($rdata['batch_id']); ?>
```

Comment: oh i see what my problem was i didn't end it. i left out the semicolon ;. thanks

Answer (score 133):

The correct function name is [strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php). If you want to apply this on each element of the array, you can use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$array = array('ONE', 'TWO');
$array = array_map('strtolower', $array);
```

Now your array will contain 'one' and 'two'.

Comment: For a good one off without editing the contents of my array:

if(!in_array(strtolower($filename[0]),array_map('strtolower', $filesArray))){

Comment: `array_map('mb_strtolower', $string)` if there is a possibility of have non-english characters in your string: [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5c67223f0a0a17d743d98854a1c43737996333e9)

Answer (score 12):

If you have a bunch of arrays with key-value pairs and you want to change the keys to lower case only, then this is your solution:

```
$lower_array_keys = array_change_key_case($array, CASE_LOWER);
```

Take a look at *[array_change_key_case](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php)*.

Answer (score 7):

[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is preferred, but another solution is:

```
foreach($array as &$v) {
  $v = strtolower($v);
}
```

Note that the ampersand `&` makes the `$v` modifiable.

Comment: Make sure to always do "unset($v);" after a foreach loop with an '&' in it. Or make sure not to use '$v' anymore in the same scope. Otherwise anything new assigned to $v will be put in your original array. Example where stuff goes wrong: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6b6c3a779d5c43cebee4020786f6090632f33822

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to use `array_map` which returns an array containing the results of applying the callback `strtolower` to the corresponding index of array.

```php
array_map('strtolower', $rdata['batch_id']);
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67105053/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at the strtolower signature, it doesn't mention any references:

```
string strtolower ( string $str )
```

So your code won't modify the value of $rdata['batch_id']:

```
<?=$rdata['batch_id']?>
strtolower($rdata['batch_id']);
```

But this code would:

```
$rdata['batch_id'] = strtolower($rdata['batch_id']);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the array to a string containing the array data in JSON, convert it to lower case and then convert back to an array.

Note: This method is only useful for index(not associated) Array.

```
$lowerarray = json_decode(strtolower(json_encode($mixedarray)));
```

Comment: This sollution can technically work but it's not a right way to do. If you use this for an associated array then this will mess it up.

Comment: @ARN what about not associated array?

Comment: For indexed arrays this method will work but it's not recommend. Use array_map(), array_walk() or a foreach to accomplish this

Comment: If you update your answer with it's limitations it would be a great improvement.

Comment: @ARN above method is perfect for indexed(not associated) array this method is less memory consumption and less time consuming, if you have thousand records then foreach will take too much time, by this method you can increase efficiency of code, Thanks

Comment: Its a great method for only indexed array and faster but not for the associated array.